# Add Metabox to settings / options page

Tags: metabox, theme-options

I am looking to add a metabox to an options page I have created using ACF. I have tried just about everything without success.  I have created many metaboxes with custom post types but never with an options pages. Below is the code I have been trying to work with.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'adding_businessHours_shortcode' );
function adding_businessHours_shortcode( ) {

    // I have tried the to add the page with the following 
    $pages = array(
        'theme-options_page_theme_business_hours',
        'admin.php?page=theme_business_hours',
        'theme_business_hours'
    );

    add_meta_box( 'businessHoursShortcodes', __( 'Shortcodes', 'theme' ), 'displayBusinessShortcodes', $pages, 'normal', 'low' );
}

function displayBusinessShortcodes(){
    // content here
}
```

Comment: My initial answer would have been - you can't do it because that's not how WP options pages work, but, you if really want a metabox on an options page, you CAN make it happen - though I am not sure what complications ACF may pose for you. The solution proposed and tested at this site is demonstrated in detail in the answer to a question at this site here:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57092/creating-custom-meta-boxes-on-plugin-option-pagein

Comment: I have read through the page you linked but that only works if I do not use ACF.  It uses the same variable to declare everything.  I cant find how to pull information from ACF.  I have to use it because I have many fields being created using their api.